# Syntax error with multiple expressions in one-line block

Tags: ruby

I get a syntax error but I'm not sure what would be the desirable alternative in Ruby to accomplish the same thing:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :019 > Dvd.find_each { |x|  x.save, puts x.length }
SyntaxError: (irb):19: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
Dvd.find_each { |x|  x.save, puts x.length }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dvd.find_each { |x|  x.save; puts x.length }`

Try semicolon ; instead of ,

Comment: Thanks. I seen some samples using comma instead of semicolon. Could you explain the differences?

Comment: Comma separates method arguments and such, semicolon separates logical lines always. You might have seen something like this: "puts x.save, x.length", which would stand for "puts( x.save, x.length )".

Answer (score 4):

Or, just for the fun of it, use our new #tap method added into Ruby 1.9:

```
Dvd.find_each { |x| puts x.tap(&:save).length }
```